# Check if two mathematical expressions are equivalent

Tags: algorithm, tree

I came across a question in an interview. I tried solving it but could not come up with a solution. Question is:

[Edited]
First Part: You are given two expressions with only "+" operator, check if given two expressions are mathematically equivalent. 
For eg "A+B+C" is equivalent to "A+(B+C)".

Second Part :  You are given two expressions with only "+" and "-" operators, check if given two expressions are mathematically equivalent. 
For eg "A+B-C" is equivalent to "A-(-B+C)".

My thought process : I was thinking in terms of building an expression tree out of the given expressions and look for some kind of similarity. But I am unable to come up with a good way of checking if two expression trees are some way same or not.

Can some one help me on this :) Thanks in advance !

Comment: You want to invent a [**canonical form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form) for such expressions.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the operations are commutative, the solution I'd propose is distribute parenthetic operations and then sort terms by 'variable', then run an aggregator across them and you should get a string of factors and symbols. Then just check the set of factors.

Comment: A-B =!= B-A, so theyre not commutative here

Comment: Actually : Addition is commutative. The sign of the factors is different : 

[1]A + [-1]B  =!= [1] B + [-1] A

Comment: My point is *subtraction is not commutative* so I’m not sure how your answer applies to the question

Comment: Subtraction is the addition of negatives.

Comment: The point is that you don't evaluate the variables, only the constant factors until you get to a state where there is a single terms per variable.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate variable counts until encountering an opening brace, treating subtraction as addition of the negated variable. Handle sub-expressions recursively.

The content of sub-expressions can be directly aggregated into the counts, you just need to take the sign into account properly -- there is no need to create an actual expression tree for this task. The `TreeMap` used in the code is just a sorted map implementation in the JDK.

The code takes advantage of the fact that the current position is part of the `Reader` state, so we can easily continue parsing after the closing bracket of the recursive call without needing to hand this information back to the caller explicitly somehow.

Implementation in Java (untested):

```
class Expression {
   // Count for each variable name
   Map<String, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<>();

   Expression(Srring s) throws IOException {
     this(new StringReader(s));
   }

   Expression(Reader reader) throws IOException {
     int sign = 1;
     while (true) {
       int token = reader.read(); 
       switch (token) {
         case -1:  // Eof
         case ')':
           return;
         case '(':
           add(sign, new Expression(reader));
           sign = 1;
           break;
         case '+':
           break;
         case '-':
           sign = -sign;
           break;
         default:
           add(sign, String.valueOf((char) token));
           sign = 1;
           break;
       }
     }
   }

   void add(int factor, String variable) {
     int count = counts.containsKey(variable) ? counts.get(variable) : 0;
     counts.put(count + factor, variable);
   }

   void add(int sign, Expression expr) {
     for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : expr.counts.entrySet()) {
       add(sign * entry.getVaue(), entry.getKey());
     }
   }

   void equals(Object o) {
     return (o instanceof Expression) 
        && ((Expression) o).counts.equals(counts);
   }

   // Not needed for the task, just added for illustration purposes.
   String toString() {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : expr.counts.entrySet()) {
       if (sb.length() > 0) {
         sb.append(" + ");
       }
       sb.append(entry.getValue());  // count
       sb.append(entry.getKey());    // variable name
     }
     return sb.toString();
   }
 }
```

Compare with

```
new Expression("A+B-C").equals(new Expression("A-(-B+C)"))
```

**P.S:** Added a `toString()` method to illustrate the data structure better.

Should print `1A + 1B + -1C` for the example.

**P.P.P.P.S.:** Fixes, simplification, better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the expressions from left to right and reduce them to a canonical form for comparison in a straightforward way; the only complication is that when you encounter a closing bracket, you need to know whether its associated opening bracket had a plus or minus in front of it; you can use a stack for that; e.g.:

```js
function Dictionary() {
    this.d = [];
}
Dictionary.prototype.add = function(key, value) {
    if (!this.d.hasOwnProperty(key)) this.d[key] = value;
    else this.d[key] += value;
}
Dictionary.prototype.compare = function(other) {
    for (var key in this.d) {
        if (!other.d.hasOwnProperty(key) || other.d[key] != this.d[key]) return false;
    }
    return this.d.length == other.d.length;
}

function canonize(expression) {
    var tokens = expression.split('');
    var variables = new Dictionary();
    var sign_stack = [];
    var total_sign = 1;
    var current_sign = 1;

    for (var i in tokens) {
        switch(tokens[i]) {
            case '(' : {
                sign_stack.push(current_sign);
                total_sign *= current_sign;
                current_sign = 1;
                break;
            }
            case ')' : {
                total_sign *= sign_stack.pop();
                break;
            }
            case '+' : {
                current_sign = 1;
                break;
            }
            case '-' : {
                current_sign = -1;
                break;
            }
            case ' ' : {
                break;
            }
            default : {
                variables.add(tokens[i], current_sign * total_sign);
            }
        }
    }
    return variables;
}

var a = canonize("A + B + (A - (A + C - B) - B) - C");
var b = canonize("-C - (-A - (B + (-C)))");
document.write(a.compare(b));
```